# How to connect an existing C++ program to SQL Server database, replacing Access db?

Tags: c++, asp.net, sql-server

I have a C++ library to calculate some scientific results behind a web application. Currently it is reading the data from Access db where the source path is one of the inputs from ASP.NET application.

```
locst_DataConnection.Format(_T("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=%s"), laa );
```

Now we are migrating this data to SQL Server. I tried to pass connection string like this

`locst_DataConnection.Format(_T("%s"), laa );`

where `%s` is defined as

```
@"Provider=SQLOLEDB; data source=xxxx\sql2012; initial catalog=xxxx; user id=xxx; password=xxxx"
```

But it did not work to add the provider - which library references do I need to add?